# Why I am getting 24 as output for this code

Tags: c

I am entering this code and it is giving answer 24 why??

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int a = a;
    printf ("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `24`?

Comment: Aayush Tiwari What do you expect?

Comment: undefined behaviour

Comment: Code is not initializing the variable 'a' before it is being used .Uninitialized variable can have any value. we cannot predict its value. You might see different value on next run.

Comment: I am getting `0`. May be because `gcc-6` puts in specific value of `0` rather than letting the program crash. What is your compiler and which architecture are you compiling on?

Please post what do you expect as the result.

Answer (score 3):

You code doesn't initialize variable `a`.
Without initialization your variable `a` has some random value at the memory address it's  assigned to. If you run the code again, you might see that `24` is not the output, but it's some other random number.

This is common with any uninitialized variable. As, when you declare a variable, compiler assigns a memory address for them. The initial value is random.

Initializing variable - `int a = 5;`